# How to pipe diff into Kompare?

Tags: command-line, kde, diff, file-comparison

I want to quickly compare files in two different directories to see if the files are the same (same content). I want to see the results in Kompare (I'm on KDE - Kubuntu 12.04).

Here's my diff command:

```
diff -EwbBsy /directory/one /directory/two
```

(That command would suit me even better if it ignored any files in /directory/one that are not already present in /directory/two, but I couldn't figure out how to achieve that.)

To use Kompare, I do this:

```
diff -EwbBsy /directory/one /directory/two | kompare -o -
```

However, that gives the following error:

> **Error:** Could not parse diff output.

I also tried:

```
diff -Ewbus /directory/one /directory/two | kompare -o -
```

and just

```
diff /directory/one /directory/two | kompare -o -
```

and a few other variations without success.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Are you opposed to using kdiff3 instead of kompare?

Comment: I'm not opposed to kdiff3, but it isn't installed by default and kompare is installed.

Comment: It's a KDE app, but yes, you'd have to install it. Is that an option?

Comment: Your comparing all the files in dir one with dir two, or is the one and the two files?

Comment: @slm Yes I am comparing all the files in dir one with dir two. Normally, it would compare fileA in dir/one with fileA in dir/two, then do the same with fileB, fileC, etc.

Comment: I installed kdiff3, but I can't (so far) pipe diff output into kdiff3 from the command line using the approach I tried for kompare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be able to handle the `-y` switch which does the side-by-side style of diff, but you can use the unified diff (`-u`). You can't mix these 2 styles so it's either `-y` or -`u`. So doing this worked for me:

```
$ diff -EwbBsu /directory/one /directory/two | kompare -o -
```

This will not show the entire file with the matches, just the line that was different, with 3 lines of context, by default. If you want more context you can provide `-u` a argument of a number (`u 10`) for example.

```
$ diff -EwbBsU 10 /directory/one /directory/two | kompare -o -
```

Comment: That's strange. I still get the same error with your command `Could not parse diff output.` Maybe my problem is with kompare. However, kompare works fine in normal GUI usage.

Comment: @MountainX - it works fine in normal for me as well. What version are you using? `kompare --version` Qt: 4.7.4
KDE Development Platform: 4.6.5 (4.6.5) Kompare: 4.0.0.

Comment: kompare --version
Qt: 4.8.1
KDE Development Platform: 4.8.5 (4.8.5)
Kompare: 4.1.2

Comment: @MountainX - What's the distro?

Comment: Kubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: @MountainX - there was a typo in my 2nd command. Sorry about that. I've fixed it. Should've been a `-U` not a `-u`.

Comment: thanks. It still isn't working for me. Maybe the problem is my version of diff: `diff (GNU diffutils) 3.2`

Comment: @MountainX - mine's 2.8.1.

Comment: thanks. Seems like this functionality is broken in more recent versions of diff, kompare and/or kdiff3.